# How to do reports from python

Tags: python, reporting, pdf

This is not a question, asking for a (single) tool, although to answer my question, of course tools are involved. The focus of this question is, asking for advice in which direction to head for.

I have a JAVA-background, so in order to generate any document, Jasper Reports are a good starting point.

Coming to Python, I am facing the requirement, that our customer wants either PDF output oder (ideally) .docx (Office 2010). Since Office 2010 is able to read `.odt`, my first approach was using `py3o` to do the job in Libreoffice. But that was a bit dissatisfying. The compatibility between Libreoffice and MS Office isn't as good as expected.

Would it be a better approach to target `PDF` and use LaTeX to generate the document? I took a look at `weasyprint` which generates PDF from HTML and CSS. The demo looks quite promising, but I hesitate to use CSS for the job.

My question is: what is the common way to deal with "reports" under python?

P.S.: I should mention, that the software is required to be Open Source or has to have at least a community version

Comment: Weasyprint can be found at http://weasyprint.org/

Comment: Reporting seems to be an afterthought, as it is with most platforms these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two popular ones:

[pyPDF2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2)

[ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/)

As far as I know ReportLab has a free and paid version.

Comment: Thank you very much. Reportlab looks promising. But i forgot to mention: it has to be free software. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well I was reading and they have the open-source version meaning you'll have to redistribute the software as open source as well. That how I understood it. :)

Comment: It is not the solution, I hexpected or hoped for, but since no other answers are available, I accept this one ;)

Comment: Well I got a downvote. I was just supposed to comment it but sadly didn't have enough reputation points yet. The answer accepted was much appreciated.

Comment: It wasn't me ;) I can not understand the decision to downvote. Reportlab is a fair choice.